# CORS Issue using flask_socketio and React

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, flask-socketio

I am getting a CORS error when trying to connect my frontend react with my backend flask.

My backend should be accepting requests from all origins, and my front end is simply just trying to connect, and hopefully display a form.

This is more of a cors issue, and I tried all sorts of things such as origins=None, origins=*, taking away origins completely, etc. etc. and nothing changes. It does look like the socket is connected, but not sure how to, or where to manually set the header?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMuE8.png)

[Frontend :3000 - React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x91cR.png)

[Server :5000 - Flask-socketio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTfoV.png)

Comment: The error message indicates that the server is returning a 500 error. Have you investigated that? Please add the server logs to your question, as that is likely related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following the below method helped to avoid CORS issue in flask.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Doc - https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/